# Can we average the coefficients from bootstrapped samples for Logistic Regression with L1 regularization?

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, bootstrap, lasso, importance

I have a model built using logistic regression with L1 regularization (`glmnet package`). I built this model using 1% of total data available to me. To ensure that the variance of my result is small, I am now planning to run bootstrap on my available data. I am just not sure how to "aggregate" the final coefficient that I will be using to make "predict"?

Is this a right approach? If not what are some ways to go about this?

Comment: I think it would be better to bootstrap the predictions from each model.  At least in that case, you can have the other predictions in order to create bootstrapped confidence intervals.

Comment: I really thought about this and my conclusion is that we cannot do so. This is because Lasso chooses 1 variable among 2 highly correlated variables. But we do not know which variable it chooses. So, when we average out 2 models, we might be averaging between mutually exclusive set of variables. So, it doesn't make any sense to average out the variables.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402267/how-to-obtain-confidence-intervals-for-a-lasso-regression

Comment: Tell us why you used only 1% of data! If you want model averaging, then ridge will be closer ...

Comment: I have around 300 million rows. And because of computation limitation, I ended up choosing around 2-3 million rows