# LASSO vs. Standard Variable Selection via p-value

Tags: p-value, feature-selection, lasso

How can I reason about compare/contrast variable selection between

1. LASSO
2. running a standard multi-variate regression and setting betas to zero if the p-value is > 0.05

?

Comment: This is not multivariate analysis.  You have a single dependent variable.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is this: you should not, under any circumstances, do the second one.

Statisticians have been crying and screaming at scientists for decades. This is not an appropriate use of p-values. A nonsignificant p-value does *not* mean there is no effect. All it means is that you have not rejected the null hypothesis.

Moreover, stepwise regression invalidates your p-values and creates inconsistent confidence intervals, unless the model-building process is taken into account.

LASSO is different. LASSO will automatically try to identify useless coefficients and set those to 0, when it is appropriate. Use LASSO and not stepwise regression (the thing where you set coefficients to 0 if they’re not significant). You can also use ridge regression, or a Bayesian model.

Comment: One additional remark for OP is that model building should be taken into account in the case of LASSO as well when constructing confidence intervals or conducting hypothesis tests. Please refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/402276).

Comment: I find your answer rather misleading. First, none of your criticism of $p$-values is relevant if the modelling goal is prediction. Second, almost all of it applies just as well to LASSO when the modelling goal is inference. (What does not apply is *Statisticians have been crying and screaming at scientists for decades*.)

Comment: Richard I'm not understanding your criticism of the criticism.

Comment: @RichardHardy This applies even if the modelling goal is inference. p-values should not be used to set coefficients to 0, ever, because a failure to reject the null is not a confirmation of the null. The null hypothesis can only be rejected, never accepted, and a large p-value does not provide evidence that the coefficient in question is actually 0. This is a severe misinterpretation of p-values. If you'd like to search for evidence that supports the null, you can do a Bayes factor analysis (although I personally would advise against that given the well-known problems associated with them).

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I am trying to say that in situations where you do not use p-values to begin with (like in prediction), you do not care whether the p-values are valid or invalid. When the sun is shining, you do not care whether your umbrella is broken or not; that is simply irrelevant.

Comment: @RichardHardy in that case, p-values are even worse. You should never be using p-values for prediction, period, because the goal of a p-value is inference and is wholly unrelated to prediction. You can use LASSO, ridge regression, or drop predictors which worsen AIC, but trying to figure out the right variables to include from p-values will probably make your predictions worse than just including everything.

Comment: It is not as clear cut as you make it. See e.g. [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=aic+15.7). There are also studies showing that forward stepwise selection can be competitive with LASSO and other methods in prediction. Hastie et al. ["Extended comparisons of best subset selection, forward stepwise selection and the lasso"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08692) (2017) is one of them. In any case, this does not address my original criticism; it still stands.

Comment: @RichardHardy It's absolutely as clear-cut as I'm making it. The threads you linked are full of people pointing out that you should not use p-values for variable subset selection. Best-subset selection can definitely be competitive when there are many useless predictors and only a handful of good ones, as the paper you linked shows, but best-subset selection should be done with a measure of model quality like AICc or Mallows' Cp, not with p-values. p-values should never be used for variable selection.

Comment: I respect your opinion but I think my explanation and references explain how you got this wrong. I rest my case.

Comment: Best subset variable selection often performs horribly.

Comment: That is also correct. It depends on just how heavy-tailed/sparse you expect your coefficients to be. If there's a handful of variables with obscenely large effect sizes hidden among some completely useless variables, best subset variable selection can outperform LASSO. Otherwise LASSO wins.